# Opening and appending files

Tags: java, file, append

I need to open an existing file for appending and create new file for appending if it doesn't exist.

I tried `PrintWriter` function but it always create a new file and deletes the old. So could you help me? What should I use for that?

UPD: That's what I already tried

```
writer = new PrintWriter(System.getProperty("db.file"), "UTF-8");
writer.println("The first line");
```

Comment: what ahve you tried so far? show us some code!

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-append-content-to-file-in-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("your_file.txt", true)));
```

The true parameter of FileWriter indicates it has to append data.

To add specify encoding you can use

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                     new FileOutputStream("your_file.txt", true), "UTF-8")));
```

Comment: But how to append using UTF-8?

Comment: new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("your_file.txt"), true), "UTF-8")));